# How can this complex TradingView strategy be converted into an alert for 3commas trading bot?

Tags: bots, pine-script, trading

I am entirely new to code and was following a YT tutorial to convert TV strategies to studies with alerts for short and long positions. These alerts aim to notify two 3commas bots (one long and one short) to place trades automatically.

My issue arose when I failed to identify the longSignal and its closing signal and the shortSignal and its closing signal. Unlike the strategy script in the YT tutorial, this script contains no mentions of long or short signals.

I attempted using the Pine tutorials on Kodify to understand the issue and how it may be solved, but evidently, I am not fit to identify an appropriate solution. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

This is the script for the strategy:

````
//@version=4
strategy("The Strategy", overlay=true)
start = input(0.02)
increment = input(0.02)
maximum = input(0.2)
var bool uptrend = na
var float EP = na
var float SAR = na
var float AF = start
var float nextBarSAR = na
if bar_index > 0
    firstTrendBar = false
    SAR := nextBarSAR
    if bar_index == 1
        float prevSAR = na
        float prevEP = na
        lowPrev = low[1]
        highPrev = high[1]
        closeCur = close
        closePrev = close[1]
        if closeCur > closePrev
            uptrend := true
            EP := high
            prevSAR := lowPrev
            prevEP := high
        else
            uptrend := false
            EP := low
            prevSAR := highPrev
            prevEP := low
        firstTrendBar := true
        SAR := prevSAR + start * (prevEP - prevSAR)
    if uptrend
        if SAR > low
            firstTrendBar := true
            uptrend := false
            SAR := max(EP, high)
            EP := low
            AF := start
    else
        if SAR < high
            firstTrendBar := true
            uptrend := true
            SAR := min(EP, low)
            EP := high
            AF := start
    if not firstTrendBar
        if uptrend
            if high > EP
                EP := high
                AF := min(AF + increment, maximum)
        else
            if low < EP
                EP := low
                AF := min(AF + increment, maximum)
    if uptrend
        SAR := min(SAR, low[1])
        if bar_index > 1
            SAR := min(SAR, low[2])
    else
        SAR := max(SAR, high[1])
        if bar_index > 1
            SAR := max(SAR, high[2])
    nextBarSAR := SAR + AF * (EP - SAR)
    if barstate.isconfirmed
        if uptrend
            strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=nextBarSAR, comment="Short")
            strategy.cancel("Long")
        else
            strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=nextBarSAR, comment="Long")
            strategy.cancel("Short")
plot(SAR, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color=color.orange)
plot(nextBarSAR, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color=color.aqua)
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)```
````

Comment: Questions and answers need to be separate on Stack Overflow. If you have an answer to your question, you can post an answer below in the answer field. You can even accept your own answer to indicate that this is the solution you ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `alert()` function inside `uptrend` condition with desired message type template from your bot

```
alert("Your token message for long trade")
```

so:

```
//@version=4
strategy("The Strategy", overlay=true)
start = input(0.02)
increment = input(0.02)
maximum = input(0.2)
var bool uptrend = na
var float EP = na
var float SAR = na
var float AF = start
var float nextBarSAR = na
if bar_index > 0
    firstTrendBar = false
    SAR := nextBarSAR
    if bar_index == 1
        float prevSAR = na
        float prevEP = na
        lowPrev = low[1]
        highPrev = high[1]
        closeCur = close
        closePrev = close[1]
        if closeCur > closePrev
            uptrend := true
            EP := high
            prevSAR := lowPrev
            prevEP := high
        else
            uptrend := false
            EP := low
            prevSAR := highPrev
            prevEP := low
        firstTrendBar := true
        SAR := prevSAR + start * (prevEP - prevSAR)
    if uptrend
        if SAR > low
            firstTrendBar := true
            uptrend := false
            SAR := max(EP, high)
            EP := low
            AF := start
    else
        if SAR < high
            firstTrendBar := true
            uptrend := true
            SAR := min(EP, low)
            EP := high
            AF := start
    if not firstTrendBar
        if uptrend
            if high > EP
                EP := high
                AF := min(AF + increment, maximum)
        else
            if low < EP
                EP := low
                AF := min(AF + increment, maximum)
    if uptrend
        SAR := min(SAR, low[1])
        if bar_index > 1
            SAR := min(SAR, low[2])
    else
        SAR := max(SAR, high[1])
        if bar_index > 1
            SAR := max(SAR, high[2])
    nextBarSAR := SAR + AF * (EP - SAR)
    if barstate.isconfirmed
        if uptrend
            strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=nextBarSAR, comment="Short")
            alert("Your token message for long trade")
        else
            strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=nextBarSAR, comment="Long")
            alert("Your token message for short trade")
plot(SAR, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color=color.orange)
plot(nextBarSAR, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color=color.aqua)
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

and then create an alert with `The Strategy` condition  and `alert() function calls only` in the alert settings with the web hook URL.
[image]

Comment: To clarify, do I do what you said while still having the script as a strategy or should it be a study?

I would be happy if it worked without the conversion to a study, but until now, all tutorials and websites said it would only work if it's a study, not a strategy.

Comment: Alerts work perfect with strategies. No need for converting script to study. This is probably an old video/tutorials.

Comment: Could you please walk me though it once more? I don't quite understand what and how exactly I should be doing.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The rest should be understandable from the bot tutorial you using.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but  the method was incompatible with the 3commas bots. I resulted to converting it to a study and got it working last night. 
(I will update the thread with the script)